# Is it possible to show that the eigenbasis is the most 'optimal' basis for a given linear transformation (if it exists)? How would you measure this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

Given a linear transformation, a coordinate transformation to the eigenbasis (if it exists) seems the most optimal and easiest to calculate. An eigenvector expressed in other coordinates always seems to be more complicated to write. For example for an eigenvector ${\bf v}_1$ in eigenbasis we have:

$$ {\bf v}_1 = 1 {\bf v}_1 $$

which seems trivial. But if we use a arbitrary different coordinate system we get

$$ {\bf v}_1 = c_1 {\bf w}_1 + c_2 {\bf w}_2 + \dots + c_n {\bf w}_n $$

It always seems you need more basis vectors to express this eigenvector than in its eigenbasis. Is this true?

Can you define a 'most' optimal coordinate system and are there any theorems about which are the most 'optimal'?

Comment: Short answer: No. What's optimal depends on the application. An eigenbasis is often the most useful basis.

Comment: @bananenheld We can show that the eigenbasis makes a linear transformation as [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) as possible, perhaps this is a result that you'd be interested in

Comment: It's not true you need more basis vectors to express $v_1$ in another basis. Replace $v_1$ by $av_1$ (assuming $av_1\neq 0$) for example and you need only $1$ vector to express $v_1$ in that basis, but these are the only examples. Of course you need more vectors if the basis does not contain any multiple of $v_1$.

Comment: There is nothing special about eigenvectors here. The reason you can express eigenvectors with fewer basis elements in the eigenbasis is that an eigenbasis is formed from eigenvectors. If you have some other breakdown of the whole space $V$ as a sum of disjoint subspaces, $V = V_1 + V_2 + \cdots + V_k$ with $V_i \cap V_j = \{0\}. i \ne j$, then you can likewise form a basis for $V$ by combining bases for each of $V_i$, and you will find that vectors in the various $V_i$ will be more simply expressed in terms of this basis than other vectors in $V$. "Eigen" is just one way of so expressing $V$.